# Create a completely new template for YARD?

Tags: ruby, yard

I need to change the structure of the HTML documentation generated by [Yard](http://yardoc.org); there isn't much in common with the default HTML template.

As I understand it, the solution to this is to create a new YARD template,  but I'm having trouble creating one. The [YARD documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Templating_YARD) and an [old blog post on customizing on this topic](http://gnuu.org/2009/11/18/customizing-yard-templates/) seem to be geared more towards tweaking the existing template.

I was hoping that someone can help me with some references or samples on creating a brand new YARD template.

Comment: Did you take a look to the template architecture docu? http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Templates.md

Comment: Yes I did. I also had a co-worker look at the YARD template architecture independently. He came to the same conclusion as me, that the existing documentation is weak on this topic.  The YARD docs seem to be geared more towards extending or tweaking the existing templates.

Comment: In the intervening five and a half years since the last activity on this question YARD has not improved their documentation for template generation. I have found only one YARD template that has been created since then, https://github.com/SketchUp/sketchup-yard-template.